# Firestore Security Rule:Add data based on timestamp value

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular6, firebase-security

I want to read or write some data from/to firestore based on a security rule that enforces user to correct his local machine date should be correct ,means neither past nor future.If the client machine time is not correct, he does not have the ability to read or write data;

now i have tried with security rule

```
 service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
  allow read:if true;
  allow create: if (request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time.toMillis());
  }
 }
}
```

but it always shows a message that permission denied.How can achieve this.?

my code is

```
  batch.set(ref, {
    timestamp: new Date().valueOf(),
    name: formData.name ? formData.name.toLowerCase() : null,
    type: formData.type ? formData.type : 'percentage',
    rate: isNaN(formData.rate) ? 0 : Number(formData.rate),
    date1: formData.date1 ? new Date(formData.date1) : null,
    date2: formData.date2 ? new Date(formData.date2) : null,
    time1: formData.time1 ? formData.time1 : null,
    time2: formData.time2 ? formData.time2 : null,
    id: ref.id,
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    typeArray,
    enabledDays: dateArray,
    isActive: true,
    isTotalEnabled: formData.dOnTotal,
  });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time.toMillis()`. Are you expecting both timestamps to match down to a millisecond? Don't think it's possible (network delay, code execution delay...), you need to give it a bit more breathing space (like 10 - 15 seconds maybe).

Comment: How can i give a breathing space? can you please explain it? Or is there any way to check whether the client date is today date or not using firestore security rule?

Comment: Please see my answer. How precise you need to be (seconds, minutes, hours) ? Do you care about time zones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.resource.data.timestamp == request.time.toMillis()`. Give it a bit more leeway (10 s for example):

```
math.abs(request.resource.data.timestamp - request.time.toMillis()) < 10000;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.if the leeway time is more than that of we mentioned,we can't make any read/write operation.How can we overcome this scenario?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Judging by the example of rules you gave, you dont want to allow **write** operation if record timestamp does not match server time. My example calculates absolute difference between two timestamps (in milliseconds) and check if its smaller than some leeway const. If not - there will be no write allowed (permission denied error). Please be aware this is not taking into account timezone differences (as I assume your  record is created by client browser code - not by cloud function)

Comment: i applied your answer it perfectly works and i got your points.But it is my curiosity to know that is there any better way rather than this.?

Comment: @ MrAleister: is it possible to apply your answer to the delete operation?i think it is only aware of update and create operations;for delete operation it will show an error of 'permission denied';

Comment: If you're going to do this for whatever reason make sure you account for timezone differences between device and server if your app doesn't automatically use a the standard timezone Firebase does.